Error: Required parameter "opts['policySid']" missing. How to know which policy is needed dynamically
Our app needs to use Twilio so users can send sms to their customers. The architecture is as follows.
Our app has the main twilio account.
User signs up, we create a subaccount for them.
When they purchase phone numbers those drill down from our account to their subaccount. In order to send sms the user has to do either toll free verification or 10dlc campaign registration.
Both of these are done after the user creates a brand.
The issue im running into is an error regarding.
Error: Required parameter "opts['policySid']" missing. Now as I look deeper into policies im hitting a rabbit hole.

Here is what my users need: They need to have 10DLC and toll free numbers on their subaccount; they need to be able create to toll-free verifications, a brand, and 10DLC campaigns. They also need to be able to make phone calls. It looks like the policy I need is called "Secondary Customer Profile of Type Business." However, The docs say not to hardcode the policy sid because it will change over time. Can I just add a function like this here,
 const fetchPolicies = async () => {

try {

const policies = await client.trusthub.v1.policies.list();

// Filter the policies based on your requirements

const policy = policies.find(p => p.friendlyName.includes("Secondary Customer Profile of type Business"));

if (policy) {

selectedPolicySid = policy.sid;

} else {

console.error('No appropriate policy found');

}

} catch (error) {

console.error('Error fetching policies:', error);

}

};

To fetch the policy based on the friendly name?
Will this change over time?
How am i supposed to know if it changes?
Does this require us to basically query policies everyday and if it changes we have to make the change in our app?
The policies thing is really really confusing to me, it looks like there are over a 1000? I am needing this to create the secondary customerProfile for the subaccount when the user registers for our app.
We need this customerProfile so they can do toll free verification and create 10DLC campaigns.
Also do we need to use other trustHub products and add the customers purchased phone numbers to a trustHub product?
Does not simply adding the phone number to the subaccount work anymore?
